# Como faço para passar um valor do javascript para o PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html-select, html-option

Tenho um select que lista todos os meus jogadores:

```
<select name="jogador" id="cod_jogador">
    <option name=""></option>
    <?php foreach($jogadores as $jogador): ?>
        <option id="codigo" value="<?= $jogador['cod_jogador']?>">
            <?= $jogador['nome']?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Quero que quando o usuário escolher um jogador a variavel $cod_jogador seja preenchida com o value desse select, para isso fiz esse script:

```
<script>

select = $('#cod_jogador');

select.bind("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'idc-comparacao-jogador.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            'codigo': $('#codigo').val()
        }
    }).done(function(data){

        console.log(data);

        $('#codigo').val('');

    });
});

</script>
```

O problema é que no data ele retorna o código HTML da pagina e não o valor do meu value, alguém poderia me ajudar? Como passo o valor do meu option para meu PHP

Comment: Use $('#jogador option:selected').val(); para pegar o valor do option selecionado

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente no `<option...>` não pode ter o `id="codigo"` pois onde tenha mais de uma opção vai ter mais de um id com o mesmo nome "codigo" e isso não pode.

```js
<select name="jogador" id="cod_jogador">
    <?php foreach($jogadores as $jogador): ?>
        <option value="<?= $jogador['cod_jogador']?>">
            <?= $jogador['nome']?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

```js
<script>

$("body").on("change", "#cod_jogador", function(){
    select = $('#cod_jogador').val(); //Obtemos o valor do select com id="cod_jogador"
    $.ajax({
        url: 'idc-comparacao-jogador.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            codigo: select,
        }
    }).done(function(data){

        console.log(data);

    });
});

</script>
```

Para que a resposta do data seja o código somente o conteúdo de idc-comparacao-jogador.php deveria ser algo parecido com:

```
<?php
    echo $cod_jogador = $_POST['codigo'];
?>
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou, ele continua retornando a mesmo código html, será que pode ser porque a url do meu ajax esta sendo direcionada para o mesmo código que ele esta sendo executado?

Comment: Se a URL é a mesma sim, é devido a isso, ajax recebe tudo o que é "impreso" na tela por assim dizer, alí no fim deixei o código que deveria ter o .php, tenta criar um novo .php e nele botar aquelas 3 ultimas linhas, logo bota esse arquivo pra ser chamado na URL do ajax.